# does training on total dataset improves confidence scores

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using SVC(kernel="linear", probability=True) in multiclass classification. when I'm using 2/3rd of my data for training purpose, I'm getting ~72%. And when I tried to predict in production, Confidence scores I'm getting are very less. Does training on the total dataset helps to improve confidence scores?

Comment: You, possibly (if I understand the explanation correct), overfit your model.

Adding more data usually helps to train the model better. But, I suppose, this is not your main problem at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does training on the total dataset helps to improve confidence scores?

It might. In general, the more data the better. However evaluating performance should be done on data that the model has not seen before. One way to do this is to set aside a part of the data, a test set, as you have done. Another approach is to use cross-validation, see below.

> And when I tried to predict in production, Confidence scores I'm getting are very less.

This means that your model does not generalize well. In other words when presented with data it has not seen before the model starts to make more or less random predictions.

To get a better sense of how well your model generalizes you may want to use  [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = SVC()
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, Y)
```

This will train and evaluate your classifier on the full dataset using folds of the full data. A fold  For each split the classifier is trained and validation on an exclusive subset of the data. For each split the `scores` result contains the validation score (for SVC, the accuracy). If you need more control over which metrics to evaluate, use the [`cross_validation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics) function.

> to predict in production

In order to improve your model's performance, there are several methods to consider:

- Use more training data
- Use an [ensemble model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) to reduce prediction variance
- Use a different model (algorithm)

Comment: Usually using more data results in LESS overfitting, not more.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I agree, I removed the misleading statement.